# cannot find ssl libraries?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, nagios, nrpe

I am trying to install nrpe plugin on ubuntu 12.04, however I am facing issue with ssl libraries. I tried installing "libcurl3-openssl-dev" package, however when I try to compile nrpe plugin after installing this package I am facing issue saying "cannot find ssl libraries".

Could anyone please shade some light on this?

Thanking you,

Regards,
Gaurav.

Answer (score 14):

If you're running on 64-bit:

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --with-ssl-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

For whatever reason the configure script for nrpe doesn't seem to be able to find where libssl-dev installs the libraries. You can find where Ubuntu puts them with

```
apt-file list libssl-dev
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried the above options by compiling the nrpe plugin by giving the exact path of the ssl libraries. It gets compiled, however I am unable to locate check_nrpe in "/usr/local/nagios/libexec" & the result command "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost" fails saying "connection refused by host". Have opened 5666 port in /etc/services, however its not showing the details in netstat -at | grep nrpe or 5666. 
 Kindly help me for the same.

Comment: I've never done this but http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2009/04/nagios-nrpe-host-server-and-client-on-centos-ubuntu.html indicates that you may need to copy the nrpe and nrpe_check binaries to the right locations from the src directory by hand.

Comment: Installing package `libssl-dev` fixed mine (Debian Stretch).

Answer (score 6):

**Ubuntu:**

Run this:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

**centos:**

Run this:

```
yum install -y openssl-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate SSL Libraries
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Oct  4 18:12 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.2k
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 470376 Aug  9 07:08 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k

## ln -s /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k /usr/lib64/libssl.so

Answer (score 0):

I keep facing with issue of Hash Sum mismatch with apt-get update with the default sources list.

By just changing to another mirror which is close to where I am, I can finally install the libssl-dev.